# Where is the notes app on nexus s?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, notes

Is there a native notes app? I cant find it

Comment: If there isn't a native app, see [What do you use for note taking?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/305/what-do-you-use-for-note-taking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a native notes app for the Nexus S because it doesn't have TouchWiz UI. I'm quite certain the voice action 'Note to self' actually sends an email to yourself (I don't personally use that action, not sure it likes a British accent)

There are loads of third party apps though. For example [**Scribb.it**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lioncode.notepad&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5saW9uY29kZS5ub3RlcGFkIl0.) is full to the bursting with features, [AK Notepad](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.akproduction.notepad&feature=search_result) is quite a good simple one or [Evernote](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.evernote&feature=search_result) has a strong following and quite a few more features.

Answer (score 0):

The Touchwiz Memo app has been ported to ICS, you can grab it on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1529223) (this is in the Vibrant xda forum sub-section, but it works on other phones).

This app works on JB too, you simply have to install it as a regular apk (not in system/app)